# Sum up all "amount" fields in a Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5

I am trying to get the total amount collected in a month, let's say January.

I am able to retrieve all the `created_at` fields which were created in the month of January in the `$main_data_January` variable. The `$main_data_January` variable contains this type of [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtd1v.png).

As you can see, each item has a field called `amount`.

#### Problem

I want to retrieve the value of `amount` field from each item and sum them up. As I'm doing it in the `total_earnings_janunary`, but this is where I am facing the problem.

By adding both the amounts, the expected result should be **13000**, but
the result is **8000**. It is only getting only the first value of amount after being in a loop.

```
$customers = Tag::all();
$total_earnings_janunary = 0;
    
$query_date = '2017-01-04';
$start_date_janunary = date('Y-01-01', strtotime($query_date));     
$end_date_janunary = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($query_date));  

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    if (Auth::User()->gym_code == $customer->gym_code ) { 
        $main_data_janunarys = DB::table('tags')->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date_janunary,$end_date_janunary])->get();
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i <= count($main_data_janunarys); $i++) {
    $total_earnings_janunary = $total_earnings_janunary + $main_data_janunarys[$i]->amount;
    dd($total_earnings_janunary);            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things to note:

- You're querying the `Tag` model and storing it in `$customers`. Resulting entities are not customers. Make sure that's intended.
- In the first `foreach` loop, you are overwriting previous value of the `$main_data_janunarys` over and over. Use `break` if that's intended.
- In the `for` loop, you are `dd`ing early. Move it outside the loop and you'll see your intended results. In the loop exit condition you should be using `<` instead of `<=` as you're starting from zero.
- To sum up the collection you could just use [`Collection::sum()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1402) method, like: `$main_data_janunarys->sum('amount');`.

Comment: if dd it outside the for loop it is giving a error `Undefined offset: 2` and when use `$main_data_janunarys->sum('amount');`  it is giving 0 as answer

Comment: That's because of the `<=` operator in the `for` condition. Change it to `<` as you're starting from zero.

Comment: Dunno if you noticed my edit on your question or not, the results is not JSON-formatted, it's just a PHP variable dump which looks like JSON.

Comment: Yeah you are right, actually I am a bit more a java person myself so that's my mistake and I apologize for that!!!

Comment: No need to apologize, Himanshu. It was just a friendly note. Good luck with your php journey.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$customers = Tag::all();
$total_earnings_janunary = 0;

$query_date = '2017-01-04';
$start_date_janunary = date('Y-01-01', strtotime($query_date));     
$end_date_janunary = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($query_date));  

foreach ($customers as $customer)
{

 if( Auth::User()->gym_code == $customer->gym_code ) {             

     $main_data_janunarys = DB::table('tags')->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date_janunary,$end_date_janunary])->get();

    }
}

$total_earnings_january = $main_data_januarys->sum('amount');
```

You can read further about Laravel's Collection [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sum)